# Smoothing out a Stochastic Process

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes

For a stochastic process $G(t)$, one technique of making the process continuous is to define a process $G^m(t) := \int_0^t m e^{m (s-t)} G(s) ds$.  I would like to understand the intuition behind such a definition and verify that it is in fact continuous almost surely.  Furthermore, it is claimed that $G^m$ converges to $G$ in the $L_2$ sense as $m \rightarrow \infty$.

Are there more natural methods to smooth out stochastic processes?

Comment: Well, $G^m$ is the convolution of $G$ with a smooth function... and therefore it has very nice regularity properties.

Comment: I suppose you are assuming that $G$ is square-integrable?

Comment: Yes, it's square integrable.  thanks!